# Detect Missing Dll in own folder

Tags: c#, dll, runtime-error

I'm trying to prevent my program from getting any error messages. So far I tried to use try statement to detect my error. But when I try to move Dll into another folder from my application. Framework error occurs at first, although the framework give me a specific error, my goal is to create my own error message.

[image]

Comment: Side note: Why? Do you also want to report nice error when .exe for your program itself is deleted :) ? For this particular class of errors (someone changing/removing files of your program) it may be easier to rely on OS permissions (i.e. install in "program files" where normal users don't have write access) rather than catching all errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but you must be sure that your process will be in *stable* state after catching these kind of exceptions. Its also good practice to handle the exception at applicatino level using [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but this will catch only thoes exceptions which could be handled by `try-catch` block.

> Corrupted process state exceptions are exceptions that indicate that
>   the state of a process has been corrupted. We do not recommend
>   executing your application in this state. By default, the common
>   language runtime (CLR) does not deliver these exceptions to managed
>   code, and the try/catch blocks (and other exception-handling clauses)
>   are not invoked for them. If you are absolutely sure that you want to
>   maintain your handling of these exceptions, you must apply the
>   HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute to the method
>   whose exception-handling clauses you want to execute. The CLR delivers
>   the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses
>   only in methods that have both the
>   HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute and
>   SecurityCriticalAttribute attributes, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There you go :) you just have to use. Look in the link

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

http://mike.woelmer.com/2009/04/dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions-in-winforms/